# Error: You need to include some adapter that implements __karma__.start method

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to add some unit tests to one of my projects.

So far I've installed and configured karma, and have installed jasmine. I've one test file in my `test/` folder.

The karma server has started, the browser page is ready, but `karma run` fails as follows:

```
$ karma run karma-conf.js 
[2014-06-14 15:19:11.046] [DEBUG] config - Loading config /foo/test/karma-conf.js
Waiting for previous execution...
Chrome 35.0.1916 (Linux) ERROR
  You need to include some adapter that implements __karma__.start method!
```

This error message doesn't Google well.

Is this something obvious, or do I need to provide more information?

Comment: Wanted to note I was receiving this error due to preprocessor syntax errors I hadn't noticed at first.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

It does seem like this is a very general error, however in my case the problem was either that I didn't run `karma start` from the correct folder, or that I didn't restart it after changing the configuration.

I'll leave this question open and hopefully it can become a resource for others who experience this error message.

Comment: Same for me - running `karma start test/karma.conf.js` did the trick for me. The right directory may be different for you.

Comment: I got this error when adding preprocessors: {
      'src/**/*.js': ['babel']
    },
any ideas?

Comment: For me changing `test/**/*.{js,jsx}` to `test/**/*.+(js|jsx)` fixed this error. How bizarre!

Comment: Also such error can appear if karma config has typo

Comment: In my case, if I scroll a little up, it shows real error: "```Error during file loading or preprocessing```" (followed by "```WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.```")

Comment: In my case, it was defective tests. Replacing the set with fresh trivial tests showed that the config file was fine.

Answer (score 33):

If you name your karma config file `karma.conf.js`, you can simply type `karma start`.

Otherwise specify the filename `karma start karmafile.js`

*(I was in the right directory, but was not specifying a file name.)*

Answer (score 13):

You need to run your `karma run` or whatever function in the folder where  karma-conf.js is in.

Comment: This doesn't seem right. If I run `karma start` in `src` subfolder where `karma.conf.js` is located I get error `[karma-server]: Server start failed on port 9876: Error: The '@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma' karma plugin is meant to be used from within Angular CLI and will not work correctly outside of it.`

Answer (score 9):

In my case I had to rename the file to **karma.conf.js** then do karma start

Answer (score 7):

I had a problem with `karma.conf.js` file code format:

```
files: [
    // Modules
    ,"client/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"
    ,"client/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"
    // App
    ,"client/app/app.module.js"
    // Test
    // ,"test/**/*.spec.js"
],
```

The extra comma in `files` array have cause this error:

```
You need to include some adapter that implements __karma__.start method!
```

Comment: Changed my files path from './dist/ to 'dist/' and everything started working. './dist' worked in the browser, but would not work in chromeHeadless

Answer (score 6):

I was not running **karma start** command from the path where my karma.conf.js was. I switched to that folder and ran the same command. Thats all

Answer (score 4):

I was facing this issue while running specs on the Angular.js codebase. I had to run `npm install karma-jasmine -g` to get this working.

Answer (score 3):

If you typing "karma start", you must have a karma.conf.js file in the current folder. or just "karma start /path/karma.conf.js"

Try to create a new karmar.conf.js by "karma init /path/karma.conf.js"

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was applying by mistake the commonjs preprocessor to the `karma-*` modules and the `adapter.js` from `karma-chrome` and `karma-firefox` was broken this way.

Unfortunately, this is a very generic error.

Comment: Could you provide more background into the fix you did? This might be getting me right now as I know I am using karma-chrome. Thanks!

Comment: Do you apply the commonjs preprocessor (is it configured in karma runner)? If yes, make sure that it's not applied to the files in the karma-* modules.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error because the project was using Babel 6 and I had forgotten to add the babelrc file. Just sharing in case this could help.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the message was in fact very descriptive: I forgot to add an adapter, in my case Jasmine, into the config file. Thus:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
      browsers: ['Chrome'],
      singleRun: true,
      frameworks: ['jasmine'],
      files: [
          // ... files ...
      ],
      // other configs
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure your "my.conf.js" file, because it contains all the info to use to test your code.

All what you need to write is this:

The configuration file can be generated using karma init:

```
$ karma init my.conf.js
```

Which testing framework do you want to use?
Press tab to list possible options. Enter to move to the next question.

> jasmine

Do you want to use Require.js?
This will add Require.js plugin.
Press tab to list possible options. Enter to move to the next question.

> no

Do you want to capture a browser automatically?
Press tab to list possible options. Enter empty string to move to the next question.

> Chrome

What is the location of your source and test files?
You can use glob patterns, eg. "js/*.js" or "test/**/*Spec.js".
Press Enter to move to the next question.

> *.js
>   test/**/*.js

Should any of the files included by the previous patterns be excluded?
You can use glob patterns, eg. "**/*.swp".

> Press Enter to move to the next question.

Do you want Karma to watch all the files and run the tests on change?
Press tab to list possible options.

> yes

Config file generated at "/Users/vojta/Code/karma/my.conf.js".

Answer (score 2):

You must specify the  **karma configuration file** to karma.

```js
karma start karma.config.js
```

It works for me

Answer (score 1):

I must add that in my case karma was giving me the error because I had [square] brackets in the name of one of the parent folders.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was not karma-related at all!  I run karma from gulp, with ES6/babel, and there was actually a code syntax error, flagged by a babel error above my karma:

> ERROR [preprocessor.babel]: xxx.js: Unexpected token (19:83)

I fixed that in my src and karma was happy again.

Answer (score 1):

Tt's complaining about the adapter which is probably jasmine or mocha.
Either the adapter is missing, either is not setup correctly, either it's an outdated or buggy version of the adapter.

In my case I had an old version of mocha 2.5.3 which was not compatible with karma 1+.
**I updated the mocha dependency to the latest version** available 3.2.0 and the problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

While working on numerous vaguely described errors, I tried setting basePath: '../',  After correcting other errors (like missing commas that were described as object content errors) the last change back to basePath: '',  got karma to work.  karma's error statements need a lot of work. It is not simple to get it going.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. My browser would open but on my terminal it threw the following error

```
30 08 2017 11:19:28.272:INFO [Chrome 58.0.3029 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected `enter code here`on socket 5sSs6E5KmpUVRp6LAAAB with id 93886631
Chrome 58.0.3029 (Linux 0.0.0) ERRORSome of your tests did a full page reload!
```

I checked my karma.conf.js file. In the framework array , i had included jasmine and requirejs. But i had only installed karma-jasmine.Removing requireJS and rerunning the karma start worked!

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with this too. What I came up to is that this error occurs because one of the following reasons

- No [test adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/karma-adapter) installed or defined ([frameworks property in karma.conf.js](https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html)
- No karma configuration found (ie, no `karma.conf.js` in current dir or no config file specified in command)

My problem was that my config file was named `karma.config.js` instead of `karma.conf.js`.

If you've installed the *test adapter* but it still doesn't work, try running `karma init` and go through the guided config setup.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to specify the directory of `karma.config.js` when you run start karma.

Try

`karma start karma.config.js`

Answer (score 1):

I had a bad 'files' configuration in my karma.conf.js

```
files: ['**/*.js'],
```

this caught up all the files in node_modules/ including those of the karma-jasmine plugin, as it was seen as sourde files it wasn't loaded on startup. Changing to

```
files: [
        'src/*.js',
        'spec/*.js'
    ],
```

solved the problem in my case

Answer (score 0):

FWIW - sourcing the file path of `karma.conf.js` worked for me locally, but not on my jenkins builder. I have zero clue why this is the case, but on jenkins it was throwing this error unless the `karma.conf.js` file was in the root directory where the karma command was given. I'm using rails and running the js specs through a rake task. Code is below which might be helpful for some.

https://gist.github.com/daino3/a39486ff8bfc1668e923

Answer (score 0):

The issue in my case was that karma didn't pick up any files. Fixing it in karma.conf.js solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue happened to me, and it was due to an outdated module.

Running `npm update` solved it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the **configuration file name was different**. So, running the command specifying the **conf** file solved my issue.

```
>> karma start unit-tests.conf.js
No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
...
```

And for 'PhantomJS', opening the link specified(**localhost:9876**) in the browser executes the test cases.

Hope it helps. :)

**EDIT 1: My Karma Config File**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      './node_modules/angular/angular.js',
      './node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
      './node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      './app/services/users/users.js',
      './app/app.js',
      './app/services/users/users.spec.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['spec'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I received this error because I required the same dependency twice!

Removing the duplicate file dependency removed the error for me. Circled in blue below.

[image]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: @ggorlen--onLLMstrike feel free to update the answer from image to text

Comment: That's an awful lot of typing to expect others to do. Usually, the author of the post would simply _copy-paste_ the text from their terminal or text editor, saving everyone the trouble and enabling them to easily do the same, while avoiding data limits, saving bandwidth and making the content accessible to search and screen readers (among other benefits), as described in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

Given this is the first result on google for this error message, I figured I'd mention my resolution here.

I was getting this error after converting an AngularJS 1.8 project to Typescript and trying to change over my Karma tests to use the typescript preprocessor.

I finally realized that adding `import angular from 'angular'` resolved the issue on Karma's side, but then `angular` turned up as undefined in webpack's build.

Eventually thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43479510/12869266) on a question about *that* error message, I updated my import statements to `import * as angular from 'angular'`, and finally it worked! (Ultimately I had to resolve every compilation error on every typescript file for complete resolution, which I had been somewhat ignoring since the webpack build worked.)

Hopefully this can help someone with this problem!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but above mentioned solutions didn't work for me. What I eventually found out is that my karmaWebpackConfig was using "babel-loader" as loader. I just removed that line and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `karma-typescript` and after searching for a long time i finally thought about looking into the Browser-Console and i saw the error:

```
876/context.html:1 Refused to execute script from '....ts'
because its MIME type ('video/mp2t') is not executable.
```

As it turns out... Karma is using a package 'mime' to check if the script is exectuable and it assumes that `.ts` is the `.ts`-Videoformat and not typescript.

To fix this issue you need to add the following to your `karma.conf.js`:

```
mime: {
        "text/x-typescript": ["ts","tsx"]
      }
```