# how to run tests with karma in another host's browser?

Tags: javascript, linux, windows, unit-testing, karma-runner

My general problem is how to run unit tests with karma in IE or other browser installed on a Windows machine, while karma is run on a Linux machine, though in the question below I might ask more specific question based on what I've already tried.

Also it may be worth to mention, that I have Windows installed on a Virtual box machine.

I started karma from a terminal, then opened in IE this url: `http://10.0.2.2:9876` and saw the karma page in the browser window (though I spotted some quick blink with a red background, I suppose it is related to an error I'll mention further).

After that I tried to run tests with the command: `node_modules/karma/bin/karma run config.js` in another terminal tab. When I did this I got this error (I get it even when I use Chrome on my Linux host-machine instead IE on the Virtual box guest, so I suppose the error has nothing to do with networking):

```
You need to include some adapter that implements __karma__.start method!
```

I googled for this error and found another question: [Error: You need to include some adapter that implements __karma__.start method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24220888/error-you-need-to-include-some-adapter-that-implements-karma-start-method)
Supposing that I need to run tests from the same place I started karma-server I tried to redirect the output to another tab:

```
$node_modules/karma/bin/karma start &> /dev/pts/17 &
$node_modules/karma/bin/karma run config.js
```

But this did not help. If I try to start server and run tests in a single command, then I do not have time to register IE.

So could anyone please answer any of the next questions:

- how to run unit tests with karma in a browser on other machine?
- how to get rid of this error `You need to include some adapter that implements __karma__.start method!`, if the karma server was started in one terminal tab and the `run` command was issued in another?
- how to start the karma server and run tests in separate steps, i.e. issue the `karma start` and `karma run config.js` commands instead of `karma start config.js`?

My regards and sincerest appreciation in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I've found a workaround for this. I start karma with the config file:

```
 karma start config.js
```

in the config I have `singleRun: false`.

Then I manually connect my IE instance, and after this I run the tests from another terminal tab. Why this happens I have no idea. The only inconvenience is that I always have browsers' windows open.