# Karma Testing React with ES6/Babel

Tags: javascript, testing, karma-runner, babeljs

I am trying to test my project using karma as my test runner, using the webpack babel-loader. The code all builds successfully (i think? or the CLI says it does, but when i open the browser all files fail immedialey on the es6 imports. Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
    basePath: '',
    // frameworks: ['jasmine', 'karma-webpack'],

    files: [
        'lib/bundle.js'
    ],

    exclude: ['*.styl'],

    preprocessors: {
        'test/**/*.js': ['webpack'],
        'test/**/*.jsx': ['webpack'],
        'src/**/*.jsx': ['webpack'],
        'src/**/*.js': ['webpack']
    },

    plugins: [
        require("karma-webpack")
    ],

    webpack: {
        entry: './src/entry.js',
         module: {
             loaders: [
                {
                    test: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),  
                    loader: 'babel-loader?stage=0&optional=runtime',
                    excludes: /node_modules/,
                    options: {
                        optional: ['runtime']
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    test: /\.styl$/,
                    loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'stylus-loader']
                }
            ]
        },
        webpackMiddleware: {
          noInfo: true
        }
    }
});
};
```

10 11 2015 13:16:47.156:INFO [karma]: Delaying execution, these browsers are not ready: Chrome 46.0.2490 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0)
Chrome 46.0.2490 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0) ERROR
  You need to include some adapter that implements **karma**.start method!

Chrome 46.0.2490 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0) ERROR
  You need to include some adapter that implements **karma**.start method!

[image: browser errors here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the final file that works.

Two things I was doing wrong (1 as noted in the comments below):

1. I was adding untranspiled code to the files array, which of course breaks in the browser. From Karma's documents, "Files is a list of files/patterns to load in the browser,' so of course it broke on jsx on es6 tokens.
2. I wasn't selecting jasmine as my framework so the Karma runner had no idea where to start which is why I was getting the start method error.
3. Lastly, I needed to include my tests in the files array, otherwise Karma will not load my tests and run them. (**Note: the tests must be included in the preproccssor array as well**).

   ```
   var path = require('path');

   module.exports = function(config) {

   config.set({

       basePath: '',
       frameworks: ['jasmine'],

       files: [
           'lib/bundle.js',
           'test/**/*.jsx',
           'test/**/*.js'
       ],

       exclude: ['*.styl'],

       preprocessors: {
           'test/**/*.js': ['webpack'],
           'test/**/*.jsx': ['webpack'],
           'src/**/*.jsx': ['webpack'],
           'src/**/*.js': ['webpack']
       },

       webpack: {
           entry: './src/entry.js',
           module: {
                loaders: [
                   {
                       test: /\.js$|.jsx$/,
                       loader: 'babel-loader?stage=0&optional=runtime',
                       excludes: /node_modules/
                   }, 
                   {
                       test: /\.styl$/,
                       loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'stylus-loader']
                   }
               ]
           },
           webpackMiddleware: {
             noInfo: true
           }
       }
   });
   };
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You're including the transpiled files in your test. See for example this line in your error:

```
WARNING in ./~/routes/dist/routes.js
Critical dependencies:
1:406-413 This seems to be a pre-built javascript file. Though this is possible, it's not recommended. Try to require the original source to get better results.
@ ./~/routes/dist/routes.js 1:406-413
```

Why is a `dist` file included? You should only be including `src` files and dependencies.

```
files: [
    '../node_modules/react/react.js',
    '../node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.js',
    '**/*.js',
    '**/*.jsx'
],
```

The last two don't look right. You're telling it to load all `js/jsx` files.. including the `dist` ones.

Comment: I updated with my new config -- now it looks like it's building all my files, but it says i need to implement a karma start method?

Comment: Including the `src` components shouldn't be necessary. Your `test` files will include them as necessary

Comment: Are you working from a tutorial or example? This might be a helpful example: https://github.com/webpack/karma-webpack

Comment: And this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24220888/error-you-need-to-include-some-adapter-that-implements-karma-start-method