# Error : You need to include some adapter that implements __karma__.start method

Tags: karma-runner

I'm trying to run unit tests using karma and i'm getting the error `You need to include some adapter that implements __karma__.start method!`. I tried running with `grunt` and `karma start` commands.  I did googling and all the solutions didn't work out. Not sure what i'm doing wrong. I included the right adapter which comes with karma-jasmine, which has the `__karma__.start` method, under plugins in karma.conf.js file. Here's my configuration file :-

```
 module.exports = function(config){
 config.set({
//  root path location that will be used to resolve all relative paths in files and exclude sections
basePath : '../',

files : [
  'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'node_modules/requirejs/require.js',
  'node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js',
  'app.js',
  'mainapp/mainapp.js',
  'mainapp/notes/notes.js',
  'mainapp/notes/partial/create/create.js',
  'mainapp/notes/partial/create/create-spec.js'
], 

// files to exclude
exclude: [
  'bower_components/angular/angular/*.min.js'
],

// karma has its own autoWatch feature but Grunt watch can also do this
autoWatch : false,

// testing framework, be sure to install the correct karma plugin
frameworks: ['jasmine', 'browserify', 'requirejs'],

// browsers to test against, be sure to install the correct browser launcher plugins
browsers : ['PhantomJS'],

// map of preprocessors that is used mostly for plugins
preprocessors: {
  'mainapp/notes/partial/create/create-spec.js'  : ['browserify']
},

reporters: ['progress'],

// list of karma plugins
plugins : [
  'karma-teamcity-reporter',
  'karma-chrome-launcher',
  'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
  'karma-babel-preprocessor',
  'karma-requirejs',
  'karma-jasmine',
  'karma-browserify'
],

singleRun: true

})}
```

Comment: Canonical: [Error: You need to include some adapter that implements __karma__.start method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24220888/error-you-need-to-include-some-adapter-that-implements-karma-start-method)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `requirejs` framework turns off the automatic calling of `__karma__.start`. You need to create a file that a) configures RequireJS and b) calls `__karma__.start` to kick of the tests. Here's an example. It scans through the files that Karma is serving to find the files that contains tests. This is based on a naming convention that any file that ends with `spec.js` or `test.js` is a test file. It converts the file names to module names. It then configures RequireJS. One thing it does is pass all the test modules as `deps` so that all test modules are loaded right away. It sets `__karma__.start` as `callback` so that when all modules passed in `deps` are loaded, the tests start.

```
var allTestFiles = [];
var TEST_REGEXP = /(spec|test)\.js$/i;

Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).forEach(function(file) {
    if (TEST_REGEXP.test(file)) {
        // Normalize paths to RequireJS module names.
        allTestFiles.push(file);
    }
});

require.config({

    baseUrl: '/base',

    paths: {
        'chai':             'node_modules/chai/chai',
        'chai-jquery':      'node_modules/chai-jquery/chai-jquery',
        'jquery':           'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min',
        'underscore':       '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore-min',
        'sn/sn-underscore': 'static/scripts/sn/sn-underscore',
        'vendor/jquery-ui': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min'
    },

    deps: allTestFiles,

    callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

You need to include this file in your `files` parameter in your karma.conf.js file. Since you use the `requirejs` framework, you just need to put it first in the list. For instance, if you call the file `test-main.js` (as suggested in Karma's documentation):

```
files: [
  'test-main.js',
  ...
]
```

If you load RequireJS yourself by listing it in `files`, you need to put `test-main.js` after RequireJS.

Comment: Why is someone supposed to do with this file...?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention how to include it. I've edited the answer to add that.