# ERROR: need to include some adapter that implements __karma__.start method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, sprockets

I'm trying to run Jasmine tests with Karma in our Rails application based on: http://sebastien.saunier.me/blog/2014/02/04/angular-rails-with-no-fuss.html.  I'm getting an error for both Chrome and PhantomJS:

> You need to include some adapter that implements __karma__.start method!

I took a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24220888/error-you-need-to-include-some-adapter-that-implements-karma-start-method), but all of their issues looked like outdated node modules or directory conflicts.  I've run `npm update` and should have all current versions.  Also when I run debug, all of the preprocessor output is appearing correctly, so it shouldn't be a directory issue.

Here is my karma configuration:

```js
// spec/karma/config/unit.conf.js
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path, based on tmp/ folder
    basePath: '..',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      APPLICATION_SPEC,
      'app/assets/javascripts/ng/*/*.{coffee,js,js.coffee}',
      'spec/javascripts/**/*_spec.{coffee,js,js.coffee}'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    // Preprocessors
    preprocessors: {
      '**/*.coffee': ['coffee', 'coverage'],
      '**/*.coffee.erb': ['coffee', 'coverage'],
      '**/*.haml': ['haml', 'ng-html2js']
    },

    coffeePreprocessor: {
      // options passed to the coffee compiler
      options: {
        bare: true,
        sourceMap: false
      },
      // transforming the filenames
      transformPath: function(path) {
        return path.replace(/(\.js)?.coffee$/, '.js')
      }
    },

    ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
      moduleName: 'zipapp.templates',
      stripPrefix: 'app/assets/javascripts',
      stripSufix: '.haml',
      prependPrefix: '/assets'
    },

    coverageReporter: {
      includeAllSources: true
    },

    hamlPreprocessor: {
      options: {
        language: 'js'
      }
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['PhantomJS','Chrome'],

    // If browser does not capture in given timeout [ms], kill it
    captureTimeout: 60000,

    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

Here is my rake task:

```rb
namespace :karma do
  task debug: :environment do
    with_tmp_config :start, "--single-run --log-level debug"
  end

  task start: :environment do
    with_tmp_config :start
  end

  task run: :environment do
    with_tmp_config :start, "--single-run"
  end

  private

  def with_tmp_config(command, args = nil)
    Tempfile.open('karma_unit.js', Rails.root.join('tmp')) do |f|
      f.write unit_js(application_spec_files)
      f.flush

      system "karma #{command} #{f.path} #{args}"
    end
  end

  def application_spec_files
    sprockets = Rails.application.assets
    sprockets.append_path Rails.root.join("spec/karma")
    Rails.application.assets.find_asset("application_spec.js").to_a.map { |e| e.pathname.to_s }
  end

  def unit_js(files)
    unit_js = File.open('spec/karma/config/unit.conf.js', 'r').read
    unit_js.gsub "APPLICATION_SPEC", "\"#{files.join("\",\n\"")}\""
  end
end
```

---

EDIT

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  You need to include some adapter that implements \__karma__.start method!

01:44:46 {javascript_tests} ~/$ npm list
app@1.0.0 /Users/aaron/
├── jasmine-core@2.4.1
├─┬ karma@1.1.2
```

[npm list output](https://gist.github.com/aaron-app/350170d2d661c8dc61d8c519cd212580)

---

EDIT

Looking into karma/static/context.js because of the debug

```
// Define our start handler
var UNIMPLEMENTED_START = function () {
  this.error('You need to include some adapter that implements __karma__.start method!')
}
// all files loaded, let's start the execution
this.loaded = function () {
  // has error -> cancel
  if (!hasError) {
    this.start(this.config)
  }

  // remove reference to child iframe
  this.start = UNIMPLEMENTED_START
}
// supposed to be overriden by the context
// TODO(vojta): support multiple callbacks (queue)
this.start = UNIMPLEMENTED_START
```

Looks like it's always calling `UNIPMLEMENTED_START`

Debug

> 04 08 2016 14:13:15.423:DEBUG [launcher]: PhantomJS (id 40031903) captured in 5.167 secs
>   04 08 2016 14:13:15.426:DEBUG [phantomjs.launcher]:
>
> 04 08 2016 14:13:15.427:DEBUG [middleware:karma]: custom files null null
>   04 08 2016 14:13:15.427:DEBUG [middleware:karma]: Serving static request /context.html
>   04 08 2016 14:13:15.428:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /Users/aaron/app/node_modules/karma/static/context.html
>   04 08 2016 14:13:15.429:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /Users/aaron/app/node_modules/karma/static/context.js
>   PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
>     You need to include some adapter that implements **karma**.start method!

Comment: Updating your karma frameworks to the latest versions should fix it.

Comment: Updating to 1.1.2 didn't work