# AngularJS + TypeScript: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, webpack, es6-module-loader

I'm trying to use TypeScript in an AngularJS 1.x application.

My application already uses Webpack as a module loader, so I configured it to handle the TypeScript compilation (after renaming all *.js source files to *.ts) and I managed to get it working. So it compiles without errors and generate my JavaScript output file.

The only problem is that when I run the application on the browser, it does not work and I get this console error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined

as well as:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myModuleName due to:
>   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myModuleName' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

My guess is that the object `angular` for some reason is null and it complains when I try to access `angular.module`.

I don't understand why it is so, since when I use `import angular from 'angular/angular';` in the code it compiles successfully.

The full source code is available [here](https://github.com/shindarth/othello/).

Webpack output:

`Hash: 824157db8ed6acf47fc1
Version: webpack 2.2.1
Time: 2242ms
                Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
    othello-bundle.js  1.27 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  app
othello-bundle.js.map  1.51 MB       0  [emitted]         app
   [0] ./~/angular/angular.js 1.24 MB {0} [built]
   [5] ./app/services/othello_AI.ts 8.65 kB {0} [built]
   [6] ./app/services/othello_handler.ts 9.3 kB {0} [built]
   [7] ./app/index.ts 723 bytes {0} [built]
    + 4 hidden modules`

Comment: what is your angular version ? i don't see angular in package.json or bower.json

Comment: it is 1.6 as you can see from my package.json: https://github.com/ShinDarth/Othello/blob/typescript/package.json#L9

Comment: my bad , did you checked you script order on loading  or if you load angular and angular.min at the same time ?

Comment: @DMCISSOKHO I just updated my question including the output of Webpack build

Comment: AngularJs should be include first

Comment: @DMCISSOKHO thanks, I replaced ```import angular from 'angular';``` with ```import angular from 'angular/angular';``` and with this change now AngularJS is included first. But unfortunately I still have the same issue.

Comment: Try also to move up you're index.ts

Comment: it looks like that it does not matter: I tried to remove all imports except angular so I only get 1) angular 2) index.ts  but it still gives error on ```angular.module(...)```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

When using TypeScript, AngularJS needs to be imported using:

`import * as angular from 'angular';`

The problem was that I was still importing it as I did with es6:

`import angular from 'angular';`

Comment: Thanks for this. This was driving me nuts.  I could get my app to run in webpack using angular as a global, but karma tests failed with a `You need to include some adapter that implements __karma__.start method!` error. Including an import statement immediately caused anything compiled with webpack to return the property of undefined error mentioned by the asker. Changing my import statements fixed it so I could get both working and finally have no compile errors for the first time since introducing TypeScript :D